# K8s and Helm: how can I find the PersistentVolumeClaim requirements when binding fails?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to install Gitlab from their official Helm chart `gitlab/gitlab`. One of the sub-charts is the `bitnami/postgresql` chart. I have access to the source code of both charts.

```
$ helm install gitlab gitlab/gitlab \
  --set global.hosts.domain=mando \
  --set global.hosts.externalIP=192.168.1.2 \
  --set certmanager-issuer.email=my-email@gmail.com 
  --set global.edition=ce
```

When I try to install the Gitlab chart, several containers are created, and the PostgreSQL one fails to start due to an unbound PVC. I have tried creating several different PVs that might accommodate its requirement but none of them seem to work.

```
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  23s (x14 over 8m)  default-scheduler  error while running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "gitlab-postgresql-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

I can describe the PVC and get *some* information about it, but it's not clear from the output what is missing from my PVs or what I can do do make the claim successful.

```
[mando infra]$ kubectl describe pvc data-gitlab-postgresql-0
Name:          data-gitlab-postgresql-0
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  
Status:        Pending
Volume:        
Labels:        app=postgresql
               release=gitlab
               role=master
Annotations:   <none>
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      
Access Modes:  
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    gitlab-postgresql-0
Events:
  Type    Reason         Age                     From                         Message
  ----    ------         ----                    ----                         -------
  Normal  FailedBinding  4m48s (x6324 over 26h)  persistentvolume-controller  no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set
```

So how can I find the PersistentVolumeClaim requirements when PV binding fails?

Comment: Could you provide parameters after `--set` you put when installing chart?

Comment: @KFC_ Question updated with the full command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [in the gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/storage.html) you have to manage storage on your own. You have to create storageclass, pv and pvcs by yourself.

It is recommended to use dynamic storage provisioning. 
Example `StorageClass` [object for GCP](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/blob/master/examples/storage/gke_storage_class.yml):

```
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
 name: CUSTOM_STORAGE_CLASS_NAME
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
reclaimPolicy: Retain
parameters:
 type: pd-standard
```

After creating `StorageClass`  you have to upgrade your chart by modifying [following file](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/charts/gitlab/blob/master/examples/storage/helm_options.yml) with created `storageClass`:

```
gitlab:
 gitaly:
 persistence:
 storageClass: CUSTOM_STORAGE_CLASS_NAME
 size: 50Gi
postgresql:
 persistence:
 storageClass: CUSTOM_STORAGE_CLASS_NAME
 size: 8Gi
minio:
 persistence:
 storageClass: CUSTOM_STORAGE_CLASS_NAME
 size: 10Gi
redis:
 master:
 persistence:
 storageClass: CUSTOM_STORAGE_CLASS_NAME
 size: 5Gi
```

And the upgrade your chart

```
helm install -upgrade gitlab gitlab/gitlab -f HELM_OPTIONS_YAML_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

The storageClassName on your PVC must match the one on your PV. It might be worth describing your PV and confirming that these and other properties match.

Comment: Neither the PVC nor any of my PVs have a storage class defined.

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem in alibaba cloud,

the root of this problem is a auth of your kubernetes api for create a dynamic storage in any cloud storage provider.

i apply disk-plugin and other StorageClass from [this link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/alibaba-cloud-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/disk.md#:%7E:text=If%20the%20cluster%20not%20in%20STS%20mode%2C%20you%20need%20to%20config%20AK%20info%20to%20plugin%3B%20Set%20ACCESS_KEY_ID%2C%20ACCESS_KEY_SECRET%20to%20environment%3B) and problem resolved and all pvc created.

check in all values.yml for set a name of StorageClass that access to cloud.